# Compile GCC and install to DESTDIR

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation, cross-compiling

I'm trying to install GCC into `/my/custom/path/gcc`

but for some reason it installs into the normal installation path.

the commands i'm using:

```
configure --target=i686-pc-linux-gnu --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++ --without-headers
make DESTDIR=/my/custom/path/gcc
make DESTDIR=/my/custom/path/gcc install
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The question is not really programming, so does not belongs here. However, I did answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run (in a new build tree outside of the source tree)

```
/your/source/path/to/gcc/configure --target=i686-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/my/custom/path/gcc ...
```

and then GCC will become installed in `/my/custom/path/gcc/bin/` with include files in `/my/custom/path/gcc/include/`, libraries in `/my/custom/path/gcc/lib/` etc etc

I suggest using `/opt/` or `$HOME/pub` as your prefix and you might also be interested by the `--program-suffix=-foo` option

(do that in a fresh new build tree outside of the source tree; your previous one is rotten)

After successive compilation with `make`, you can run in your build tree

```
make install DESTDIR=/tmp/mygccinst/
```

and finally, you can copy the definitive files with something like

```
cp -va /tmp/mygccinst/ /
```

You may need to run this copy as root...

PS the installation prefix is built-in the `gcc` driver binary, which actually runs `cc1` or `cc1plus` etc...